# How to run variable as shell script file

Tags: go

I need to run a variable as shell script file in golang. I tried like below code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
   var namespaceYaml string = `#!/bin/bash
docker verson`

   out, err := exec.Command(namespaceYaml).Output()
   fmt.Println(err, string(out))
}
```

But I cannot get any result. I cannot find where is the mistake.

Please anyone to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `exec.Command` isn't a shell, see the documentation, and examples: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_CombinedOutput

Comment: Why don't you just run `docker version` rather than trying to execute a script, which isn't going to work? Or, better yet, use the docker client library for Go.

Answer (score 1):

From official [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command):

> func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
>
> Command returns the Cmd struct to execute the named program with the given arguments.

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("docker", "version").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Docker version is: %s\n", out)
}
```

Useful links for further details:

- [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)
- [examples](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/example_test.go)

**Note**: make sure docker is installed on your machine.